# Программировать на Borland C++ Builder или Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, ide, c++

В какой среде лучше программировать на С++, в Borland C++ Builder или Microsoft Visual Studio. В Microsoft Visual Studio С++ немного непонятно, как начать проэкт, где инструменты формы и т.д. А в Borland C++ Builder все очень похоже на Microsoft Visual Studio VB. Но хотелось бы привыкать к той среде, которая востребована у работодателя. Т.е. в чем настоящие прграммисты пишут? ))

Answer (score 4):

В промышленном программировании продукты для разработчиков от Microsoft уже многие годы де-факто являются стандартом. Когда-то давно продукты Borland составляли им конкуренцию, но эти времена прошли. Кроме того, сейчас большинство бизнес-приложений под Windows пишется не на C++, а на C# (так проще). А Microsoft как автор C# обеспечивает этому языку лучшую поддержку в своих продуктах, нежели любой другой сторонний производитель.

Поэтому при программировании под Windows приоритет такой:

- Visual C# или Visual Basic
- Visual C++

А Borland C++ имеет смысл либо для курсовых работ в вузах, либо для поддержки древних проектов.

Comment: Не говорите глупостей, я СЕЙЧАС пишу проект в Борланде под Виндовз!
Я 5 лет проработал в Австралии и 5 лет лет в США...
И уж кому, как не мне знать - что лучше...

Comment: У меня в активе выполненные проекты для UPS и Мичиганского универа...
Ну и несколько поменьше...

Comment: Visual C# или Visual Basic - на этом пишется quick fix для ленивых и скупых... Реальные вещи до сих пор пишутся в С++...
И замены для С++ я пока не вижу...

Comment: А тех, кто пишет в Visual Basic я бы и программистами не назвал...
Это как молотком и топором делать пасочки в песочнице...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (2011)
существует экспресс-версия, привыкнешь быстро, главное начать)

Answer (score 0):

Borland C++ Builder

Comment: В Борланде я сижу с 1996 года, сделал не один проект...
Visual Studio - как и всё от Майкрософт - недружественное...

Comment: Мне тоже так сначала казалось, но потом привык...
Теперь в Borland средах работать, скажем по-мягче, не удобно :)
Один только IntelliSence чего стоит!
А используя Express версии можно разрабатывать коммереские версии программ, а Borland сначало оплатить надо.

Comment: @малыш, вообще, всё сначала недружественное, а потом привыкаешь...
Это как управлять самолётом - не знаешь для чего СТОЛЬКО кнопок, но всё же он быстрее, чем велосипед :)